# SSIS expressions on custom class/collection

Tags: c#, ssis, dts

I am trying to modify a custom DTS Task. This task creates a single report, based on values defined on properties (e.g. ReportName, ServerName, Parameter1, Value1..) in Properties window.

I am trying to modify it in a way that would allow creation of multiple reports at once. I created a collection with a custom class. I then implemented SaveToXML and LoadFromXML methods from IDTSComponentPersist. Problem is, some of these variables need to have their values defined by expressions. I cannot see the collection or class variables in Property Expressions Editor.

Is it possible to make these properties appear there? Or, is there a way to override evaluation of expressions that would allow inserting expressions into these variables?

Thank you.